# How does one covert a datetime to a different timezone using moment timezone?

Tags: momentjs

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but the code below does not end up changing the timezone.  The datetime's value never changes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
var EasternTimeZone = "US/Eastern";
var dt = "2017-05-01 08:20:29";

var centralStandardDT = moment.tz(dt, "US/Central");
var convertedToEasternTime= centralStandardTimeDT.clone().tz(EasternTimeZone);


//finalValue contains "5/1/2017 8:20:29 AM" (CST) instead of "5/1/2017 9:20:29 AM" (EST)
var finalValue = convertedToEasternTime.format("l LTS");
```

---

I need to be able to change a datetime from one timezone to another, and have the date and time reflect that change.

I'm using this setup:

moment.js (2.17.1)
moment-timezone.js (0.5.13)

Comment: Did you load the time zones that you are using?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  The timezone is part of the instantiation of the moment object, right?  I just need to feed in a datetime and then have moment-timezone change the date and time to match that of the timezone I designate (in my example central standard time to eastern standard time (1 hour difference)).

Comment: Where are you including your moment-timezone.js from? Are you using moment-timezone.js or moment-timezone-with-data.js?

Comment: I downloaded moment-timezone.js from the site and am using it.

Comment: Is there any console output? moment-timezone.js does not include the timezone data by default. You have to add the timezones you need.

Comment: I just replaced moment-timezone.js with moment-timezone-with-data.js in my solution and it appears to be working now.  I guess that is all that it needed?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the section on Data Loading in the moment.js docs. You have to load the timezone information you are using.

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/

```
moment.tz.add([
    "America/Chicago|CST CDT EST CWT CPT|60 50 50 50 50|01010101010101010101010101010101010102010101010103401010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010|-261s0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 1wp0 TX0 WN0 1qL0 1cN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 11B0 1Hz0 14p0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 RB0 8x30 iw0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 s10 1Vz0 LB0 1BX0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0|92e5",
    "America/New_York|EST EDT EWT EPT|50 40 40 40|01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010102301010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010|-261t0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1qL0 1a10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 RB0 8x40 iv0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 11z0 1o10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 s10 1Vz0 LB0 1BX0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0|21e6"
]);

moment.tz.link([
    'America/Chicago|US/Central',
    'America/New_York|US/Eastern'
]);
```

You can get the latest list here

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json

Or the alternative is to use moment-timezone-with-data.js which includes all the data. The down side there is that is is 25.3k vs 2.6k.

Comment: I just switched my solution to use moment-timezone-with-data.js instead of moment-timezone.js and it appears to be working now.  I still don't feel that I have a solid grasping of this, however.  Does my code look ok to you?

Comment: Yes. I think that you just didn't have any timezone data loaded before. The point of separating the timezone data is that there are a lot of timezones and you usually don't need all of them. They also change sometimes, so they release updates.